# Building BioJava 5.0 with Maven on Windows 10

Tags: java, maven, biojava

On a Windows 10 machine with Maven 3.5.3 and Eclipse (Oxygen) installed, I attempted to build Biojava. Unfortunately, the following output appeared after I followed the steps listed in the site, http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates/, and I don't know how to proceed.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=C__Users_CaitlinG_eclipse_java-oxygen_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.ui,4.11.0.201803080745-r
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn,4.11.0.201803080745-r
```

I have never used maven before (obviously), so I attempted to write a pom.xml file with each jar file included. Unfortunately, this too was unsuccessful as I do not know the proper structure.

Using 'maven build' from the command line for the following file:

```
<project>
<dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-alignment</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-genome</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-structure</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-structure-gui</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-phylo</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-modfinder</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-ws</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-aa-prop</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency><dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-ontology</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-survival</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-protein-disorder</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-sequencing</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
</project>
      <!-- other biojava jars as needed -->
    </dependencies>
```

...which was met with the following output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\CaitlinG\pom.xml: end tag name </project> must match start
tag name <dependencies> from line 2 (position: TEXT seen ...</dependency>\r\n</project>... @67
:11)  @ line 67, column 11
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project  (C:\Users\CaitlinG\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-parseable POM C:\Users\CaitlinG\pom.xml: end tag name </project> must match st
art tag name <dependencies> from line 2 (position: TEXT seen ...</dependency>\r\n</project>...
 @67:11)  @ line 67, column 11 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the followin
g articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ModelParseException
```

Any constructive advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

#### **Update:**

My pom.xml file has been updated to read:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <!-- for releasing to Maven Central / OSS Sonatype -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
        <version>9</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
    <artifactId>biojava</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>5.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-alignment</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-genome</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-structure</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-structure-gui</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-phylo</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-modfinder</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-ws</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-aa-prop</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency><dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-ontology</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-survival</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-protein-disorder</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-sequencing</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>

...yet the following error appeared:

--------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project biojava: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.biojava:biojava:pom:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.biojava:biojava-sequencing:jar:5.0.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <!-- for releasing to Maven Central / OSS Sonatype -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
        <version>9</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
    <artifactId>biojava</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>5.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-alignment</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-genome</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-structure</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-structure-gui</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-phylo</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-modfinder</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-ws</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-aa-prop</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency><dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-ontology</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-survival</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-protein-disorder</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
        <artifactId>biojava-sequencing</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>

<h3><b>Update:</b></h3>
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building biojava 5.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.biojava.thirdparty:forester:jar:1.038 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.biojava:biojava-sequencing:jar:5.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.771 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-30T14:27:32-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/184M
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------th the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Comment: I would start with this: the pom you're showing has a typo. Instead of `</project>
      <!-- other biojava jars as needed -->
    </dependencies>` in the last lines of the file, you should close first `</dependencies>` and then `</project>`. That is causing this error "end tag name </project> must match start
tag name <dependencies>"

Comment: Please see the update above.

Comment: org.biojava:biojava-sequencing:jar:5.0.0 doesn't exist: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.biojava/biojava-sequencing  
Try with 5.0.0-alpha15